# activemodel serializers with data as root when object is failed to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I'm using active model serializer for my API to serialize data models.

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::ApiController
  include ::ActionController::Serialization

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      return render json: user, status: :ok, root: :data
    end
    render_error(user.errors)
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end

    def render_error(errors, status = :unprocessable_entity)
      meta = { count: errors.messages.count }
      render json: errors, status: status, meta: meta, root: :data
    end
end
```

When user parameters are valid and it is saved to DB, the API returns with data as root. For example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 11
  }
}
```

However, when parameters are not valid and the user object is not saved to DB, it returns without data as root. Example:

```
{
  "email": [
    "has already been taken"
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I just want the API to return data as root for also failed scenario. Btw, the user serializer only includes `id` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify it in the JSON:

```
def render_error(errors, status = :unprocessable_entity)
  meta = { count: errors.messages.count }
  render json: { data: errors }, status: status, meta: meta
end
```